# how to get all select option values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select list

```
 <select name="select-choice-min" id="mainMenu" data-mini="true">
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      ...
 </select>
```

I tried with

```
var arr = new Array();
var sval = $("#mainMenu option").val();
arr.push(sval);
```

but on alerting arr variable I'm getting only first value 10, 10, 10, ...

so, how to get all select option values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

Loop through `#mainMenu option` using `.each()` then get appropraite values using `$(this).val()` then push using `arr.push($(this).val());`

```
var arr = new Array();
$('#mainMenu option').each(function(){
arr.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(arr)
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5m2bk/5/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like below to create an array of values

```
var arr = $("#mainMenu option").map(function(){
    return $(this).val()
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), which will create an array of all option values.

```
var arr = $('#mainMenu option').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to accomplish your task,

```
var arr = $("#mainMenu option").map(function(){ return this.value; }).get();
```